# Codename One gui builder 4.32

Tags: codenameone, gui-builder

Where is the multi selection button in Gui Builder 4.32? In previous version tutorials it appears, but not the encounter in this version. What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

That feature was removed a while back and wasn't added back as far as I recall. We had some bugs with that feature and most people didn't even notice when it was removed.

You can file an RFE in [the issue tracker](http://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/) if you want us to look into adding it back.